# mingw+glfw3 кроскомпиляция linux to windows

Tags: компоновщик, glfw

Хочу статически подключить glfw3   к своему проекту, но при линковке получаю:

> undefined reference to "glfwInit"

у меня:

os=linux; IDE=CodeBlocks; компилятор=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++; конечная цель = приложение win64;

glfw3 скачана с официального сайта и собрана  так:

> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=CMake/x86_64-w64-mingw32.cmake

билиотека libglfw3.a подключена так: -lglfw3

"nm libglfw3.a" показывает наличие символа glfwInit

весь код приводить не буду , толко упомяну #include "GLFW/glfw3.h" и вызов glfwInit(); в одной из функций, и опции компилятора "-mthreads -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXMSW__" .Вот вывод линкера:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  -o bin/win32/wxLinuxWinows.exe tmp/ReleaseWin/wxLinuxWinowsApp.o tmp/ReleaseWin/wxLinuxWinowsMain.o  -L lib/forWin64 -L lib -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -lGLEW lib/forWin64/libwx_mswu-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxtiff-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxjpeg-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxpng-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxregexu-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxscintilla-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxexpat-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a lib/forWin64/libwxzlib-3.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32.a -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -luxtheme -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -loleacc lib/forWin64/libglfw3.a -lglfw3  
tmp/ReleaseWin/wxLinuxWinowsApp.o:wxLinuxWinowsApp.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

еще: c freeglut таже проблема
еще: при компиляции под linux(g++)  проблемы нет

Answer (score 0):

Что именно от меня требовал линковщик я не понял, но проблема решилась так:
распаковал исходники glfw  в новую **свежую** папку выполнил:

> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=CMake/x86_64-w64-mingw32.cmake

и получил другую libglfw3.a  и все слинковалось

Выводы:

1) Статические объектные библиотеки скомпилированные разными компиляторами могут не подходить к нашим проектам

2)cmake для новичка не очень понятен, без сопутствующих README и руководств на официальном сайте конкретных  библиотек я бы мог бы и не решить эту проблему

3)cmake или make при повторном  запуске могут делать не то что от них ожидаешь, нужно заново распаковывать исходники перед сборкой

4)Все еще остается вопрос: как понять что не хватало линкеру, может разрядность не та, может еще что нибудь?

еще: freeglut, glew была таже проблема , решилась компиляцией их нужным компилятором

Comment: утилита  "objdump  -a libglut.a " выводит elf64-x86-64 или pe-x86-64  в зависимости от того каким компилятором была собрана, я думал что pe  и elf касается исполняемых файлов и динамических библиотек. Оказывается объектные файлы не  кроссплатформенны. Интересно можно ли компилятор заставить выводить более подробную сводку.